# How to use regex to match a sentence that starts with a number and ends with )

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the temperature range after the colon:

```
Temperature Range: 44 F to 64 F / 7 C to 18 C (upper) and 51 F to 64 F / 11 C to 18 C (lower)
```

So, the format of this values is that this string always comes after the colon, starts with a number, and ends with a right parenthesis ")". Is there a way for me to match this in regex?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
Temperature Range:\s*(^\d*.*\)$)
```

So it starts with \d and ends with ).

May I know what's wrong?

P.S., I am not writing Regex in any programming language. I am just writing Regex in a web scraping tool.

Thank you!

Comment: The `^` is causing the non-match. What is your intention by placing it there? Place it at the very beginning and you should get a match.

Comment: But I only want the value after the colon (I don't want "Temperature Range"), which is why I put the paranthesis after \s*. So ^ come after (. Right?

Comment: `^` is an anchor tag and matches at the start of a string. If you place it anywhere except at the beginning in this case, you will not get your match. The parenthesis are responsible for capturing the content, and you have them in the right place. You can place around with it here, https://regex101.com/r/hJ2hV4/1

Comment: You just need to remove ^ from your regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated regex that should work for you:

```
Temperature Range:\s*(\d+.*\))$
                      ^ ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR0iY0/1)

The `^` is a start-of-string anchor in your regex, and it causes the regex to fail the match with your input string. Also, since there must be digits after optional whitespace (`\s*`), I suggest applying `+` (*1 or more occurrences*) quantifier with `\d`.

If your string may start with anything, not just "Temperature Range", you may replace that with lazy dot matching `.*?`:

```
^.*?:\s*(\d+.*\))$
 ^^^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR0iY0/2)